# TP-Link Different Dynamic Public IP for every LAN port – Possible?

Tags: networking, router, ip-address, dynamic-ip

I have a dynamic IP home connection and I have a TP-Link router. 
Due to the business I’m running, I need to have a different public IP address for each connected device via LAN cable. 
I am not very good in networking and don't know if this can be done. 
I'm looking for any suggestion or tips. 
Did multiple Google searches but none related to what I’m looking for. 
Maybe I need to use a switch? 
If so, can somebody tell me how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Each device on your network requires a unique address to communicate.

Most home routers include a DHCP server that assigns an individual IP address to each LAN device. Just set up the desired range on the router and set the devices to automatic/DHCP.

Whether you connect the devices to one of the 'router ports' (most home routers includes an internal switch, so those ports are actually switch ports) or add a switch to any of those ports (to increase the number of ports) doesn't matter.

**Edit** as the question now asks for *public* IPs: the *one* public IP of your router is assigned by your ISP. If you require more than one public IP address you need to ask them. Note that with destination NAT there is no reason for any of your LAN devices to have a public IP address directly assigned.

If you require port forwarding aka reverse NAT aka destination NAT you can forward different (TCP) ports to different LAN devices.

You can't however forward a specific port to more than one device. For multiple web servers all on port 80 you could use a reverse proxy that forwards on the HTTP application layer.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i want the external ip to be different for each lan port(pc) connected and not a local ip like 192.16.. but an external ip, is that possible?

Comment: @HashimRoja That’s up to your ISP. The answer is most likely “no”, though.

Comment: so that's configurable on their end? that's what you mean? i gotta try and ask them hehe, really need this, i asked them for static ip addresse and cannot afford paying 10$/month for each ip

Comment: If an ipv6 address is convenient for you then you can dig out how to use a free (or no free) tunnelbroker such a hurricane electric.  So update your question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

This is doable in conjunction with support from your ISP.

You need to get your ISP to route you a subnet of IPs over your Internet interface, then you assign one if those IPs to the LAN interface on your router and allocate the rest to the DHCP pool - thus replacing the 193.168 addresses with valid ones.

There are a few gotchas though, including finding an ISP willing to do this, disabling NAT on your router (may not be required depending on firmware) and ordering and allocating the correct size block. Generally a block (subnet) is a power of 2, with the first and last IP in the block being unusable and the second or second last address being assigned to the router. This means that if you have up to 5 computers you need a /29 (8 IP addresses) for 13 you need a /28 (16 addresses), 29 is a /27 (32 addresses ) and so on.

You would generally expect to pay for IP space, and many ISPs won't support this configuration.